# How should I respond to partial answers to multi part questions?

Tags: discussion

I have a [multi part question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15680/what-are-the-common-forms-of-these-sentences), to which some parts of the question have been [successfully answered](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/15682/4729).

Now that the question has been open a while and I'm ready to give away the rest of the answers, does it make more sense to edit the "most correct" answer just to complete it, or to post my own answer?

Comment: Perhaps [this post](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3073/as-op-editing-helping-the-correct-answer) would be a little helpful?